# Creating and naming 'n' JQuery objects in a for-loop (OOP)

Tags: jquery, loops, oop, object

I'm trying to make a very ***very simple*** billiard game to practice JQuery OOP. I'm starting; and I have this code:

```
//Main ball "class"
function createBall(number, color){
  this.number = number;
  this.color = color;
}
$color = ["noColor", "yellow","blue","red","purple","orange","green"...];
$ball1 = new createBall(1, $color[1]);
$ball2 = new...
```

But, I don't want to create an object ball by ball, so I tried to use a `for`; something that works like this:

```
for(var $i = 1; $i <= 15; $i++){
  ball+$i = new createBall($i, $color[i]);
}
```

Obviously, I can't name the new object using "`ball+$i`". I'm trying to achieve this 'cause I want to use later "`ball1.color = 'red'...`" and change the object property and so.
The way that worked by now is this code:

```
$ballArray[] = new Array;
for(var $i = 1; $i <= 15; $i++){
  $ballArray[$i] = new createBall($i, $color[i]);
}
```

If I call `$ballArray[1].color`, it returns `"yellow"`, as should be; but I'm not sure if "`$ballArray[1]`" is actually the object name, or if this calls the `createBall()` function each time I 'call' this object properties and generate a new one. This probably could create tons of objects, and that's a NOPE. Am I doing it right? Or is there another way to correctly do this?

In the end, I just want to create and name all the balls objects without doing it one by one, in case I need to create 100 objects later.

Hope I have explained correctly. **All suggestions are welcome** :)

Comment: `new` is called once per array object in your code.  `new` returns an instance of `createBall`, which is stored in the array.  When you want to store a number of items of the same kind, an array is usually the right call.  By the way, to follow OOP, your class should probably be called `Ball`, not `createBall`.  The creation is happening in `new` and the object is a `Ball`.

Comment: Well, you're on the right track, but your for loop starts at 1 and arrays start indexing at 0. I would say `for (var $i = 0; $i < 15; $i++)` and then say `$ballArray[$i] = new createBall($i + 1, $color[$i]);`. As for your question about it being the object name, i'm not sure what you're asking, but I can say that any time you use the `new` keyword, it will return you an object. So in this case, each element of `$ballArray` will actually be a ball object with the properties specified upon creation.

Comment: Also, +1 to @JeffB for mentioning the class name should be `Ball` and not `createBall`. `createBall` can be a function that returns `new Ball(number, color)`, but the class itself should be called `Ball`. I ran out of characters to mention that xD

Comment: You also have the `[]` as a part of your variable name for `$ballArray`, in Javascript you would simply say `$ballArray = new Array`, or alternatively `$ballArray = [];` Side note - none of this is jQuery code, this is all plain JavaScript

Comment: Thanks a lot! I made an quickly array, thats why it started with 1 and so. About JQuery thing, wrote that cause I'm using $(...).stuff later on the code, but you are right. I'll keep trying to make this program, and clearing my code. Perhaps I don't need a name for each object (like @Rory-McCrossan said on the answer) as I was thought; just the array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I'm not sure if `$ballArray[1]` is actually the object name, or if this calls the createBall() function each time I 'call' this object properties and generatea new one.

The `$ballArray` variable holds an array containing the values that the `createBall()` constructor returns. Therefore your code is fine as you only create one instance of the object per iteration of the loop.

However there are several amendments I'd suggest to improve the quality of your code.

- `$` is used as a prefix on variables that hold jQuery objects, so is not applicable in your example as you don't use any jQuery logic at all
- call the class `Ball` as it describes what the object is. `createBall` would be more like a method name as it's a verb which describes what the logic does.
- array names don't need to be followed by `[]`
- use `push()` to add a new item to an array in the last position.
- array indexes start at `0`, so presumably your `for` loop should too

```js
function Ball(number, color) {
  this.number = number;
  this.color = color;
}

var ballArray = [];
var colors = ["noColor", "yellow", "blue", "red", "purple", "orange", "green"];

for (var i = 0; i <= 15; i++) {
  ballArray.push(new Ball(i, colors[i % colors.length]));
}

console.log(ballArray);
```

Comment: Thanks for all the advices! Didn't knew that isn't neccesary to have a name for each object- just a place to store it. I'll work with this. Finally, Should I change the question title to be on rule?